# Elasticsearch query with multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am newbie of Elasticsearch. I want filter by multiple fileds

i have some data :

```
{
    "_index": "app",
    "_type": "test",
    "_id": "2121",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "id": 2121,
      "name": "Toto",
      "category": {
         "id": 5
      },
      "state": {
         "id": 44
      },
      "stage": {
         "id": 6
      },
      "userAccepted": [ ],
      "userReferred": {
         "id": 1
      }
   }
}
```

How I can filter by name, category and state?

I tried many solutions but it does not work :

```
  {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "name:Toto AND state.id:44 AND category.id:5"
    }
  }
}
```

Or

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "category.id",
            "query": "5"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "name",
            "query": "test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Take a look at the above query and see if the helps Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's your version of Elasticsearch? I tested your first query attempt on v7.2 and it correctly returns your sample document.

If you are going for a compound `must` query, I would recommend using the `match` query. E.g.,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": { "name": "Toto" }
        },
        {
          "match": { "state.id": "44" }
        },
        {
          "match": { "category.id": "5" }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "number" : "6.8.3"